# ¿Como convertir una imagen a base64 en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un WS que recibe los siguientes datos:

```
    <token>string</token>
    <NroComputacion>string</NroComputacion>
    <NroCarnet>string</NroCarnet>
    <Foto>string</Foto>
    <Firma>string</Firma>
    <Emision>dateTime</Emision>
    <Vencimiento>dateTime</Vencimiento>
    <ObservacionesCarnet>string</ObservacionesCarnet>
```

El problema es que la foto y la firma a la hora de cargar son una imagen, que se tiene que convertir a base64 y a un string para que se realice la llamada de forma correcta, y no se como hacer la conversion o como pasar los datos.

por ahora este es mi Models:

```
     public class CarnetViewModels
{
    public class CarnetNuevo
    {
        public string Computacion { get; set; }

        public string NroCarnet { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase Foto { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase Firma { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Emision { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Vencimiento { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Este mi controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Nuevo(Models.CarnetViewModels.CarnetNuevo carnet)
    {

        var token = Session["token"] as string;
        //27662956

        SRCarnets.CarnetsSoapClient wsCarnet = new SRCarnets.CarnetsSoapClient();
        SRCarnets.RespuestaSimple outCrear = new SRCarnets.RespuestaSimple();
        outCrear =  wsCarnet.CrearCarnet(token, "27662956", carnet.NroCarnet, carnet.Foto, carnet.Firma, carnet.Emision, carnet.Vencimiento, carnet.Observaciones);
        return View();
    }
```

y mi View:

```
     <form name="nuevoCarnet" accept-charset="utf-8" action="@Url.Action("Nuevo", "Carnet")" method="POST" >
    <div class="parent">
        <img src="~/img/carnet-frente.png" class="bg" />
        <table class="overlay">
            <tr>
                <td width="30%">
                    <div width="50%">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foto, new { type = "file" })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="70%" rowspan="2">
                    <table width="100%" class="presentacionCarnet">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="25%">Carnet N&deg;</th>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NroCarnet, null)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Licencia N&deg;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>C.I. N&deg;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fecha de Nac</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nacionalidad</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Municipalidad</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Domicilio</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fecha de Emisión</th>
                            <td> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Emision, null)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fecha de Vencimiento</th>
                            <td> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Vencimiento, null)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th valign="top">Observaciones</th>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Observaciones, null)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Firma, new { type = "file"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Generar Carnet" />
                    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancelar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sebastian, cuantas imagenes mandas por 1 llamado a tu WS?

Comment: mando dos, lo hacia en javscript pero ahora lo quiero pasar asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes trabajar también en el front-end de la siguiente manera:

```js
function leerArchivo() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("imgNinja").value = e.target.result;
      console.log(e.target.result);
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", leerArchivo, false);
```

```html
<input id="inp" type='file'>
<input type="hidden" id="imgNinja">
```

Y en el server, leer el valor del imgNinja que ya se encuentra en Base64

Comment: pero en el codigo publicado se ve que el servicio lo invoca desde el controller en .net, es alli donde necesita la imagen en base64, el archivo se sube como file al servidor

Comment: entendido! espero que también la idea sea captada por el autor de la pregunta. Gracias Leandro!

Comment: Utilize tu respuesta ya que fue la mas facil de aplicar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Deberias obtener el byte[] desde el HttpPostedFileBase

```
byte[] data;
using (Stream inputStream = model.File.InputStream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
    if (memoryStream == null)
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Fuente [Convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte)

Asignando el byte[] al convert

[Convert.ToBase64String (Método) (Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

obtienes el string encodeado a base64, este es el que envias al servicio

Comment: buenas señor leandro, solo dire que soy nuevo en esto y que me cuesta entenderlo, que parte de mi codigo deberia cambiar y como?

Comment: debes cambiar tu action, antes de invocar al CrearCarnet() debes convetir el las propeidades Firma y Foto aplicando lo que comento, conviertes a byte[] y de alli a string aplciando el convert

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar la propiedad FirmaBase64 a tu clase:

```
public class CarnetNuevo
{
    public string Computacion { get; set; }

    public string NroCarnet { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Foto { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Firma { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Emision { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Vencimiento { get; set; }
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }

    public string FirmaBase64 { get {
        if (Firma == null)
             return null;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[Firma.InputStream.Length];
        Firma.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, byte.Length - 1)
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

En esta clase podés consultar el valor de la propiedad FirmaBase64 y te va a devolver lo que necesitás.
Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví gracias a la respuesta de **fredyfx**

Me quedo asi el codigo:

en mi View edite los input file asi:

```
    <div>
         <input id="imp" type='file' class="file" multiple data-show-upload="false" data-show-remove="false" data-show-caption="true"> 
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foto, new { type = "hidden" })
   </div>

   <div>
        <input id="inp" type='file' class="file" multiple data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true"> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Firma, new { type = "hidden" })
```

el input que cree con razon lo deje oculto y con esta funcion javascript los relleno

```
    function leerArchivofoto() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var FR1 = new FileReader();
            FR1.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("Foto").value = e.target.result;
            };
            FR1.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("imp").addEventListener("change", leerArchivofoto, false);

    function leerArchivofirma() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var FR2 = new FileReader();
            FR2.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("Firma").value = e.target.result;
            };
            FR2.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", leerArchivofirma, false);
```

Cambie los atributos de Foto y Firma por string

```
    public class CarnetNuevo
    {
        public string Computacion { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo Nº de Carnet no puede estar vacio")]
        public string NroCarnet { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se debe agregar una fotografia")]
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Se debe agregar una firma")]
        public string Firma { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Emision { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Vencimiento { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    }
```

y por ultimo en mi controller hice la llamada:

```
    public ActionResult Nuevo(Models.CarnetViewModels.CarnetNuevo carnet)
    {
        //obtengo el token
        var token = Session["token"] as string;
        //este sera el numero de computacion = 27662956
        //instancio mi WS
        SRCarnets.CarnetsSoapClient wsCarnet = new SRCarnets.CarnetsSoapClient();
        //Instancio el output
        SRCarnets.RespuestaSimple outCrear = new SRCarnets.RespuestaSimple();
        //realizo la llamada
        outCrear =  wsCarnet.CrearCarnet(token, "27662956", carnet.NroCarnet, carnet.Foto, carnet.Firma, carnet.Emision, carnet.Vencimiento, carnet.Observaciones);
        return View();
    }
```